# How to use the TreeViewItem that I am sending through a commandparameter? Or how to convert it to its original type?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a list of Playlists. each Playlist contains a list of songs.
All this stuff is displayed by treeView. Near each song line in a treeview there is a button which deletes current song (song which button was clicked) from a playlist of current song.
To try to know in what playList current song is contained I am using these code:

```
 <Button CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=2 ,AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Command="{Binding ElementName=treeCategories,Path=DataContext.delCompfromPL}" Content="delete"></Button>
```

OfCourse I can just get the name of song (delete button of which was clicked), search this songTitle among all playlist's songs, but it will be delete all that song from all playlists. I want it to be deleted only from current playlist (from a playlist that contains a song, button of which was clicked).

I can't get playlist name from a TreeViewItem. I am getting a treeviewItem as an object, but can't convert it to its original type - PlaylistVM. It converts only to a TreeViewItem.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your problem correctly. Try looking into the DataContext of the TreeViewItem object to get the PlaylistVM object, i.e., `var plvm = t.DataContext as PlayListVM;`. Is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: yeeeahhh)))))) thanks!!!!!))))
I have spent much time trying to solve it (I am a beginner)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *TreeViewItem* object itself is **not** the *PlayListVM* object that you provided as part of the *ItemsSource* collection, so casting from a *TreeViewItem* to *PlayListVM* will fail.

However, the *DataContext* property of the *TreeViewItem* object will contain the *PlayListVM* object you are looking for.

Hence, you can do this in your *DelCompfromPL* method:

```
private void DelCompfromPL(object obj)
{
    TreeViewItem t = obj as TreeViewItem;
    PlayListVM p = (t == null) ? null : t.DataContext as PlayListVM;
    ...
}
```

If you don't need to work with the *TreeViewItem* object in your *DelCompfromPL* method, then another and better option would be to let the binding of the *CommandParameter* bind directly to the *DataContext* property of the parent *TreeViewItem* object like this:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=2 ,AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" ... />
```

Of course, you would need to adapt your *DelCompfromPL* method accordingly:

```
private void DelCompfromPL(object obj)
{
    PlayListVM p = obj as PlayListVM;
    ...
}
```